# Can I configure AWS CloudFormation to not modify ProvisionedThroughput of a DynamoDB table on update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Is it possible to get CloudFormation to set set my DynamoDB ProvisionedThroughput on creation, but not change it when I update the stack later on? I am currently using the Serverless framework, and when I redeploy, it is resetting my provisioning back to the original values which is not desired. I tried setting the stack policy to not allow updates to DynamoDB tables, but this had no affect.

Comment: I think you'll find your question is about Cloud*Formation* ("infrastructure as code") -- not Cloud*Front* ("content delivery network").

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by writing a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) with a function that takes a DynamoDB table reference along with a default value as input, reads the specified DynamoDB table, and either returns the current `ProvisionedThroughput` as the resource output, or the default if the table is not specified or not found.

For a starting point you can take a look at [`count-asg-instances`](https://github.com/AOEpeople/cfn-lambdahelper/tree/master/count-asg-instances) in Fabrizio Branca's [`cfn-lambdahelper`](https://github.com/AOEpeople/cfn-lambdahelper) repository and adapt it to call DynamoDB APIs instead of the Auto Scaling Group ones.